# How to: Check if textarea value = 1, do function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you do a function like `$("#div1").fadeOut();` if textarea value == 1.

I found this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if(document.getElementById('#textarea1').value.length === 1)
{   
    return false;
}
```

Thanks alot

Comment: You are confusing the jQuery selector syntax (which is similar to CSS) and the id string that document.getElementById requires. The getElementById function should not be passed a string with a leading '#'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
if($('#textarea1').val() === '1'){
       //do something 
       // you could also use: $('#textarea1').val().length
}else{
```

Comment: You should use `parseInt` since you are dealing with a numeric value.  It's not really good practice to handle numeric values as strings.

Comment: I forgot an '=': this way you are comparing a stringo with a string

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
if(document.getElementById('textarea1').value.length === 1) // length value
{
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if($('#textarea1').val().length === 1) // length value
{
    return false;
}
```

Remove ".length" ti have the textarea value and not its text length

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(document.getElementById('textarea1').value.length == 1)
{   
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = parseInt($('textarea').val());

if (val == 1)
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ($('#textarea1').val().length == 1)){
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
}
```